# How do you rearange text in elements using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select all the elements with class "name" and when I click on one radio button it flips the last and first name around, so: Hanks, Tom || Tom, Hanks. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<h1>Address Book</h1>

<p>Show Names as:</p>
<input name="lastfirst" value="last" type="radio">First, Last
<input name="firstfirst" value="first" type="radio">Last, First
<div>
    <table <thead="">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>9001</td>
                <td class="name">Tom Hanks,</td>
                <td>tomhanks@moviestars.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9002</td>
                <td class="name">Bruce Willis,</td>
                <td>brucewillis@moviestars.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9003</td>
                <td class="name">Jim Carrey,</td>
                <td>jimcarrey@moviestars.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9004</td>
                <td class="name">Tom Cruise,</td>
                <td>tomcruise@moviestars.com</td>
            </tr>
            <script>

            </script>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./webassets/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
    <h1>Company Staff List</h1>

<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>9001</td>
                <td>Tom Hanks,</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9002</td>
                <td>Bruce Willis,</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9003</td>
                <td>Jim Carrey,</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9004</td>
                <td>Tom Cruise,</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery. I used a filler of .hide() because other than selecting the elements I am not sure how to do this. Just some hints would help. I am not sure how to separate the first and last name. If I could figure out how to simply swap the first and last name into a variable I could definitely figure out the rest.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='lastfirst']").click(function(){
    $(".name").hide();
  });

  $("input[name='firstfirst']").click(function(){
    $(".name").hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can separate the text using split function `input.split(/[ ,]+/);`  along with a regular expression to separate each "word" within the input. 
you could then assign each value to a new variable

ex:

```
var a = array[0], b = array[1]
```

From there you could concatenate the array values into any order you choose.

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/GQDkd/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='change_last_first']:nth(0)").prop('checked', true)
    $("input[name='change_last_first']").change(function () {
        $(".name").text(function (_, old_txt) {
            var new_txt = old_txt.split(' ').reverse();
            return new_txt.toString().replace(',,', ' ') + ',';
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML changed**

```
<input name="change_last_first" value="last" type="radio">First, Last
<input name="change_last_first" value="first" type="radio">Last, First
```

References

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text)

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

[.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)

[.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Answer (score 2):

Split it first using.
`var splStr = input.split(/[ ,]+/);`

now concatinate using `input=splStr[1]+splStr[0];`